# R: svyby print NA as 0

Tags: r, na, survey

I have a problem with svyby function, because in the result I want to print all values, but svyby automatically delete all NAs.

`result <- svyby(formula = pop, by=~col1+col2, FUN=svytotal, design = mydesign, na.rm.all = TRUE)`

How to print all the values even with 0?

UPDATE:

I found a solution by adding parameter `drop.empty.groups = FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followup: `svyby` does **not** delete `NA`s but it does (by default) delete groups that have no observations. You can use `drop.empty.groups=FALSE` to report the value (which will probably be `NA`) even for groups with no observations.

Answer (score 0):

just warning this isn't great statistical practice but i assume you have a formatting reason to do this  :-)

```
library(survey)
data(api)
x <- apiclus1
x[1,'api99'] <- NA
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=x, fpc=~fpc)
result <- svyby(~api99, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
result
result[ is.na( result ) ] <- 0
result
```

Comment: It still do not work. I think the reason is that when run svyby it already delete NA, and `result[ is.na( result ) ] <- 0` not work because there is no NA observations to make them 0.

Comment: sorry, not sure i follow you..  could you please edit your question to include a reprex?  thanks!